# Reactive WebTestClient json deserialization with inheritance issue

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

I have one API returning a List. Each item in the json output will be a subclass inherited from BaseItem.
E.g.

```
class ItemA extends BaseItem{
  Integer quantity;

  @JsonCreator
  ItemA(@JsonProperty(value="quantity", required=true) Integer quantity, ...) {
     super(...);
     this.quantity = quantity;
  }
}

class ItemB extends BaseItem {
  Boolean enabled;

  @JsonCreator
  ItemB(@JsonProperty(value="enabled", required=true) Boolean enabled, ...) {
   super(...);
   this.enabled = enabled;
  }
}
```

The webflux api serialization part is done and doing well.

I am following https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance and added @JsonCreator constructors to my subclasses. But I assume this only works for RequestBody deserialization by default.

When I tried to write test cases using webTestClient, if I just write webTestClient.get(...).exchange().expectBody(BaseItem.class)...

It won't deserialize the item to the corresponding subclasses(not instance of subclasses).

The workaround I can think of is reading as String and using my customized deserializer. But not sure if there are any other ways to achieve this gracefully.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved, just found the JsonTypeInfo annotation needed in the base class

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit your answer with a code snippet? This might help other people. Thanks!